# How to start ASP.NET applications in firefox with multiple startup projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer, debugging, firefox

I am using visual studio. I can debug one startup project using any browser I choose, because the start button at the top of VS is a dropdown that lets me choose a browser to debug with.

However, when I set multiple startup projects (in this case my client and my API), the dropdown changes, and I no longer have the option to choose a browser. My only option is "Start". Despite the fact that firefox is my default browser, this options starts all the projects in IE.

I need to debug these projects in firefox, and I need them all running at the same time or they won't work. How can I run multiple startup projects in VS and have them all start in firefox?

A quick google and SO search yielded no relevant results. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the start button there should be a drop down with a "Browse With" option.

[image]

From there you can select a default browser. If Firefox (for some reason) does not show in the list, you will have to add it.

This is using VS 2015 Community.